# Change childrens font-size in gxt ui-binder

Tags: css, gwt, fonts, gxt

I have to make the font-size of all children in a DialogBox 50% bigger. The DialogBox has a FramedPanel with all children inside a VerticalContainer. My Question is, how can I set the font-size of all children inside the FramedPanel? The Widget is created via ui-binder and GXT-Version is 3.0.7.

Thank you very much

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
xmlns:gxt="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client"
xmlns:gxtTree="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.tree"
xmlns:gxtForm="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form"
xmlns:button="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.button"
xmlns:container="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container"
ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
ui:generateKeys='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator'
ui:generateLocales='default'>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData" field="verticalLayoutData">
    <ui:attributes width="1" height="-1" />
</ui:with>

<ui:style>
    .right {float:right !important;}
    .button {padding: 5px;}
    .button-cancel {padding: 5px !important; left: 85px !important;}
</ui:style>

<ui:with field='res' type='XXX'/>

<g:DialogBox ui:field="popup" modal="true" glassEnabled="true" text="{res.analysesEditTitle}">
    <gxt:FramedPanel headerVisible="false">
        <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="vPanel">
            <container:VerticalLayoutContainer>
                <container:child layoutData="{verticalLayoutData}">
                  <gxtForm:FieldLabel text="{res.analysesEditNameLabel}" labelWidth="100">
                    <gxtForm:widget>
                      <gxtForm:TextField ui:field="name"/>
                    </gxtForm:widget>
                  </gxtForm:FieldLabel>
                </container:child>

                <container:child layoutData="{verticalLayoutData}">
                  <gxtForm:FieldLabel text="{res.analysesEditSubtitleLabel}" labelWidth="100">
                    <gxtForm:widget>
                      <gxtForm:TextField ui:field="subtitle"/>
                    </gxtForm:widget>
                  </gxtForm:FieldLabel>
                </container:child>

                <container:child layoutData="{verticalLayoutData}">
                  <gxtForm:FieldLabel text="{res.analysesEditShowLegendLabel}" labelWidth="100">
                    <gxtForm:widget>
                      <gxtForm:CheckBox ui:field="legendBox" />
                    </gxtForm:widget>
                  </gxtForm:FieldLabel>
                </container:child>

                <container:HBoxLayoutContainer addStyleNames="{style.right}" width="170px">
                    <button:TextButton ui:field="okButton" text="{res.generalButtonOk}" stylePrimaryName="{style.button}" width="80px"/>
                    <button:TextButton ui:field="closeButton" text="{res.generalButtonCancel}" stylePrimaryName="{style.button-cancel}" width="80px" /> 
                </container:HBoxLayoutContainer>
            </container:VerticalLayoutContainer>
        </g:VerticalPanel>              
    </gxt:FramedPanel>
</g:DialogBox>
```

Comment: I have already tried using css class of the Panel, with no success...

Comment: Have any code to show us? We're throwing darts blind if you don't have any code.